# What is the correct block syntax in Swift

Tags: objective-c, syntax, swift, block

so I am rewriting some Obj-C code in Swift and stumbled across a block which drives me crazy.
I've already had a look at the documentation provided by apple and some other resources here on stackoverflow. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the solution, yet. IÄve got that piece of obj-c code which I want to re-write in Swift. Maybe you can help me figuring out how to do that. I'd really appreciate it!

```
- (void)startSearchWithCompletionHandler:(PHBridgeSearchCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
```

And gets called like this:

```
[self.bridgeSearch startSearchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *bridgesFound) { ...
```

So far I came up with this:

```
var bridgeSearching : PHBridgeSearching = ...

bridgeSearching.startSearchWithCompletionHandler { (bridgesFound: AnyObject!) -> PHBridgeSearchCompletionHandler in
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the block signature is

```
void (^PHBridgeSearchCompletionHandler) (NSDictionary *)
```

then the closure should look like:

```
{ (bridgesFound: NSDictionary?) -> () in
    ...
}
```

but if you know the dictionary contains object of the same type, let's say `Int`, and the key type is `String`, then you can also write it as

```
{ (bridgesFound: [String:Int]) -> () in
    ...
}
```

Up to you whether to make it optional or not, depending on how you are using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and your efforts for answering my question!