# How to search for Phillips Hue Bridges in Swift

Tags: swift

I try to search for Bridges with the Phillips Hue SDK but I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'PHBridgeSearchCompletionHandler!'

Heres my Code:

```
let bridgeSearch: PHBridgeSearching = PHBridgeSearching(upnpSearch: true, andPortalSearch: true, andIpAddressSearch: true)

func searchForBridgesLocal() {


    self.bridgeSearch.startSearchWithCompletionHandler { (bridgesFound: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in


    }
}
```

I hope you can help.

Note: I´m using Swift 3

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481372/what-is-the-correct-block-syntax-in-swift

Comment: looking for the same thing.  any luck?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46396763/488317